# Observer with full transparency

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern, template-method-pattern

I'm implementing observer pattern in the following way:

```
interface Layer{
    void adjustString(Set<String> strings);
}

interface NotifiableLayer extends Layer{
    void layerAdjusted(Layer layer);
}

abstract class ObservableLayer implements Layer{
    Set<NotifiableLayer> observers = new HashSet<>();

    void addObserver(NotifiableLayer layer){
        observers.add(layer);
    }
    void removeObserver(NotifiableLayer layer){
        observers.remove(layer);
    }

    void notifyObservers(){
        observers.forEach(l -> l.layerAdjusted(this));
    }
}

class MyLayer extends ObservableLayer{
    @Override
    public void adjustString(Set<String> strings) {
        this.notifyObservers(); //can this be auto?
    }
}
```

And this works  of course, but whoever is implementing `ObservableLayer` needs to remember to call `this.notifyObservers()` in the `adjustString` method. This is not that of a big deal, but I wanted to see if there is a way to completely hide this.

So far, I only have this idea (using template method):

```
abstract class ObservableLayer implements Layer{
    //...methods removed for simplicity

    @Override
    public void adjustString(Set<String> strings) {
        this.doAdjustString(strings);
        this.notifyObservers(); //<---- here is auto
    }

    abstract void doAdjustString(Set<String> strings);
}

class MyLayer extends ObservableLayer{
    @Override
    public void doAdjustString(Set<String> strings) {
        //now notification is in base adjustString
    }
}
```

but here I don't like that method name changed to `doAdjustString`, and it is not anymore uniform between other layer implementations (layers that directly implement `Layer` interface).

Is there any easy way to have this functionallity, but to keep `public void adjustString(Set<String> strings)` signature in `MyLayer` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a Decorator instance that holds an `ObservableLayer` instance and delegates to it.

```java
    final class LayerDecorator implements Layer {
      final private ObservableLayer delegate;

      public LayerDecorator(ObservableLayer delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      @Override
      public void adjustString(Set<String> strings) {
        delegate.adjustString(strings);
        delegate.notifyObservers();
      }
    }
```

This assumes that calling code is working using references to `Layer` instead of `ObservableLayer`.

If calling code has to work using references to `ObservableLayer` then maybe it is better to refactor `ObservableLayer` to be an interface having the methods to register listeners, remove them and notify them. This interface also extends the `Layer` interface.

```java
   interface IObservableLayer extends Layer {
     void addObserver(NotifiableLayer layer);
     void removeObserver(NotifiableLayer layer);
     void notifyObservers();
   }
```

The abstract class `ObservableLayer` changes to implement `IObservableLayer` instead of `Layer` directly. This class remains public to support application classes to define variations of observable layers.

Next an internal decorator for observable layers can be defined as shown below.

```java
    final class ObservableLayerDecorator implements IObservableLayer {
      final private ObservableLayer delegate;

      public ObservableLayerDecorator(ObservableLayer delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      @Override
      public void addObserver(NotifiableLayer layer) {
        delegate.addObserver(layer);
      }

      @Override
      public void removeObserver(NotifiableLayer layer) {
        delegate.removeObserver(layer);
      }

      @Override
      public void notifyObservers() {
        delegate.notifyObservers();
      }

      @Override
      public void adjustString(Set<String> strings) {
        delegate.adjustString(strings);
        this.notifyObservers();
      }
    }
```

Please note how the notification is done in this case.

Now instances of `IObservableLayer` can be created as

```java
    IObservableLayer observableLayer = new ObservableLayerDecorator(new MyClass());
```

Factory methods will be helpful here as they can be defined to handle creation of various application-level observable layer classes so that the instances can be created consistently that return an `IObservableLayer` which is decorated. That will free up developers from knowing how to use the decorator and allow the decorator to be an internal utility.

Comment: Thanks for one more approach - standard "favor composition over inheritance".

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is aspect-oriented programming.

The following example uses AspectJ to intercept any `public` method execution on a class extending `Observable`, and invoke `notifyObservers()` on the same object.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class EventAspect {
    @AfterReturning("execution(public * Observable.*(..)) && target(observable)")
    public void notifyObservers(Observable observable) {
        observable.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```